# Does 2 in the DBCC LOGINFO column "Status" mean it cannot be truncated?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, dbcc

When I run the command `DBCC LOGINFO`, a few of the `Status` rows contain 2.

Now I want to check why my transaction log cannot be truncated. How do I see this? Does the 2 mean in the `Status` that they are not reusable or an action is waiting (backup, restore)? Is it saying that it cannot be truncated?

Answer (score 5):

According the the information in [this MSDN forums answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1fb51bb5-a09f-4bd6-8880-4f0c15227db5/what-does-it-mean-when-dbcc-loginfo-returns-many-rows-with-status-2-and-dbcc-opentran-returns-no?forum=sqldatabaseengine) by Sankar Reddy (and other posts when searching for *DBCC loginfo status 2*):

> Status = 2 means that VLF can't be reused (overwritten) at this time
>   and it doesn't necessarily mean that VLF is still active and writing
>   transactions to that VLF. It means that the VLF is waiting for
>   backup/REPL/Mirroring etc...

[Database Checkpoints (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189573.aspx)

> CHECKPOINT only truncates the transaction log (marks the VLF for
>   reuse) only in simple recovery model. In Full recovery, you have to
>   take log backup.

[Understanding Logging and Recovery in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.logging.aspx) by Paul S. Randal

Comment: @jwalt You'll additionally want to check sys.databases and the log_reuse_wait_desc for *why* SQL server is saying you can't reuse.